# How can I change an ImageView widget using a gif image online in android?

Tags: android, imageview

I want to get some images (which are in .gif format) from a web page and then change an ImageView widget in my app.

I found the following code on stackoverflow:

```
public static Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) {
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
        return d;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then, in the onPostExecute method, I have added the following line which doesn't work (although it doesn't give any visible error).

```
((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgWeather)).setImageDrawable(LoadImageFromWebOperations(pic_image)); //pic_image is the url which ends in .gif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
 private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

and call it as,

```
  new DownloadImageTask("//(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgWeather)")
                    .execute("//pic_image is the url which ends in .gif");
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! :)